# How do i view EventSource listeners in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, server-sent-events

I have checked the Event Listeners Tab, but it doesn't seem to show server sent event listeners.

```js
const sse = new EventSource('/api/v1/sse');
sse.addEventListener("notice", function(e) {
    console.log(e.data)
})
```

Having written the above code, is there a way to monitor all my sse named events & listeners using Chrome DevTools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps like ChatGPT and Anthropic's Claude use **SSE over fetch** not the built-in [`EventSource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource) (probably by using [@microsoft/fetch-event-source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/fetch-event-source)). It's known that you can't see EventStream in DevTools.

However, to see these in Chrome Dev Tools, I could install and enable a chrome extension: [SSE viewer](https://github.com/maltoze/sse-viewer).

### How the extension works

- listen to all network requests (using a service worker),
- detect requests with headers containing `accept=text/event-stream`, and
- replaying the responses to these to a new `EventSource` that DevTools can record